# Clearing content of text file using C#

Tags: c#, .net, text, file

How can I clear the content of a text file using C# ?

Comment: If the file doesn't exist, do you want a `FileNotFoundException`?

Comment: var fileStream = File.Open("path", FileMode.Open); fileStream.SetLength(0);

Answer (score 189, accepted):

```
File.WriteAllText(path, String.Empty);
```

Alternatively,

```
File.Create(path).Close();
```

Comment: Wow, even shorter than mine! +1

Comment: what do you mean "shorter" than yours?

Comment: @F4z: Far fewer characters.

Answer (score 20):

Just open the file with the [FileMode.Truncate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) flag, then close it:

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(@"C:\path\to\file", FileMode.Truncate))
{
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
 using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path))
 {

 }
```

Will create or overwrite a file.

Comment: Since there's no code in the block, the `using` statement offers no advantage over `.Close()`.

Comment: I'm assuming he'd be doing something with the file.

Answer (score 4):

You can clear contents of a file just like writing contents in the file but replacing the texts with ""

```
File.WriteAllText(@"FilePath", "");
```

Answer (score 2):

Another short version:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, new byte[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply write to file `string.Empty`, when append is set to false in StreamWriter. I think this one is easiest to understand for beginner.

```
private void ClearFile()
{
    if (!File.Exists("TextFile.txt"))
        File.Create("TextFile.txt");

    TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("TextFile.txt", false);
    tw.Write(string.Empty);
    tw.Close();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use always stream writer.It will erase old data and append new one each time.

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filePath))
{                            
    getNumberOfControls(frm1,sw);
}
```