# log4net delete file at runtime is it possible c#

Tags: c#, log4net

Is it possible to delete a log at runtime? What I would like to do before the application starts is deleting all logs; if that is not possible I would like to clear all logs at runtime.

Any suggestion/code snippet?

Comment: I suppose you could use a rolling file appender and have a separate process which deletes the old files.  Logging libraries don't generally *delete* logs, they create them.  What are you actually trying to accomplish and why?

Comment: I have a tool that perform certain operation and having a clean log whenever I start a process would help to see what's going. I know there is a timestamp etc.. but I would like to have a clean or delete the log if exists

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95286/log4net-set-max-backup-files-on-rollingfileappender-with-rolling-date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not supported "out of the box" from log4net. However, you could using the RollingFileAppender and create a manual class/method to clean up/delete the log file. Please refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2916628/3016125

Answer (score 2):

Yes, is it possible to clear the log files. The log file will be created by starting the program, if it doesn't exist.
To clear the files, look here: [Clearing content of text file using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695444/clearing-content-of-text-file-using-c-sharp)

Comment: Hi thanks for your time and answer but that does not work."The process cannot access the file because is being used by another process" I suppose that when I start the application log4net must lock the file.

Comment: do you have write access?

Answer (score 2):

Yet another alternative is to use the processid in the log file name - then everytime you start the app, you get a new log file:

```
<appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender, log4net">
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="D:\Logs\MyApp.log-[%processid].txt"/>
```

Comment: If you're getting %processid as a literal in your file name, be sure to add the **type="log4net.Util.PatternString"** value.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to delete the log file programmatically, I prefer to combine a RollingFlatFileWriter and a scheduled task that executes something like the following recurring daily:
    forfiles -p "C:\path to logd" -s -m *.log -d -5 -c "cmd /c del @path"

The above delete any file ending in .log that is older than 5 days.  This gives more than enough time to make sure there are copies of each day's log available in your backup archive.